# Tk not running in Visual Studio in this project but works in another project file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run my code and I can't find where the issue is to make the tk box show up. Also, can someone explain what 'self' is? I'm very new to python and code. Thanks!

BTW> This is a music player that I'm trying to create with a 'next' button to allow the user to play the next song. One last question is: does anyone know how I can add a background image to it and replace the tk buttons with icons / images?

code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer
from os import walk
import pygame

    
class MP:
    def __init__(self, win):
        # Create Tkinter window
        win.geometry('500x300')
        win.title('Jared AIT Music Player')
        win.resizable(0, 0)


        # StringVar to change button text later
        self.play_restart = tk.StringVar()
        self.pause_resume = tk.StringVar()
        self.play_restart.set('Play')
        self.pause_resume.set('Pause')

        # The buttons and their positions
        load_button = Button(win, text='Load', width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.load)
        load_button.place(x=50,y=250, anchor='center')

        play_button = Button(win, textvariable=self.play_restart, width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.play)
        play_button.place(x=150,y=250, anchor='center')

        pause_button = Button(win, textvariable=self.pause_resume, width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.pause)
        pause_button.place(x=250,y=250, anchor='center')

        stop_button = Button(win, text="Stop", width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.stop)
        stop_button.place(x=350,y=250, anchor='center')




        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False

        


    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Jared/Desktop/ECCS AIT 2021", title="Select a song", filetypes=(("wav files", "*.wav"),("all files", "*.*")))
        print("Loaded:", self.music_file)
        self.play_restart.set('Play')

    


    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            mixer.music.play()
            self.playing_state = False
            self.play_restart.set('Restart')
            self.pause_resume.set('Pause')

    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state = True
            self.pause_resume.set('Resume')
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
            self.pause_resume.set('Pause')

    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()

    ########################################################################################################       
    def next(self):
        self.file_path = (self.music_file.rsplit("/",1))[0].replace("/","\\")
        if "/" in self.music_file:
            self.file_name = self.music_file.rsplit("/",1)[1]
        else:
            self.file_name = self.music_file

        self.filenames = next(walk(self.file_path), (None, None, []))[2]
        self.file_count = 0

        for i in self.filenames:
            if i == self.file_name:
                break
            self.file_count += 1

        self.next_file = self.file_count + 1
        self.directory_limit = len(self.filenames)
        if self.next_file == self.directory_limit:
            self.next_file = 0
        self.music_file = self.file_path + "/" + self.filenames[self.next_file]
        self.file_count = 0
        mixer.init()
        try:
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
        except pygame.error as message:
            while True:
                self.next_file += 1
                if self.next_file == self.directory_limit:
                    self.next_file = 0
                self.music_file = self.file_path + "/" + self.filenames[self.next_file]
                if (".wav") or (".mp3") in self.music_file:
                    break
        mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
        mixer.music.play()
        ########################################################################################################      



root = tk.Tk()
MP(root)
root.mainloop
Tk()
```

EDITED CODE -> New issue: 'Next' doesn't work

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer
from os import walk
import pygame



class MP:
    
    def __init__(self, win):
        # Create Tkinter window
        win.geometry('500x300')
        win.title('Jared AIT Music Player')
        win.resizable(0, 0)
 

        # StringVar to change button text later
        self.play_restart = tk.StringVar()
        self.pause_resume = tk.StringVar()
        self.play_restart.set('Play')
        self.pause_resume.set('Pause')

        # The buttons and their positions
        load_button = Button(win, text='Load', width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.load)
        load_button.place(x=50,y=250, anchor='center')

        play_button = Button(win, textvariable=self.play_restart, width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.play)
        play_button.place(x=150,y=250, anchor='center')

        pause_button = Button(win, textvariable=self.pause_resume, width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.pause)
        pause_button.place(x=250,y=250, anchor='center')

        stop_button = Button(win, text="Stop", width=10, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.stop)
        stop_button.place(x=350,y=250, anchor='center')

        Next = Button(win ,text = 'Next',  width = 10, font = ('Arial', 10), command = self.next)
    

        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False

        


    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Jared/Desktop/ECCS AIT 2021", title="Select a song", filetypes=(("wav files", "*.wav"),("all files", "*.*")))
        print("Loaded:", self.music_file)
        self.play_restart.set('Play')

    


    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            mixer.music.play()
            self.playing_state = False
            self.play_restart.set('Restart')
            self.pause_resume.set('Pause')

    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state = True
            self.pause_resume.set('Resume')
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
            self.pause_resume.set('Pause')

    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()

    ########################################################################################################       
    def next(self):
        self.file_path = (self.music_file.rsplit("/",1))[0].replace("/","\\")
        if "/" in self.music_file:
            self.file_name = self.music_file.rsplit("/",1)[1]
        else:
            self.file_name = self.music_file

        self.filenames = next(walk(self.file_path), (None, None, []))[2]
        self.file_count = 0

        for i in self.filenames:
            if i == self.file_name:
                break
            self.file_count += 1

        self.next_file = self.file_count + 1
        self.directory_limit = len(self.filenames)
        if self.next_file == self.directory_limit:
            self.next_file = 0
        self.music_file = self.file_path + "/" + self.filenames[self.next_file]
        self.file_count = 0
        mixer.init()
        try:
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
        except pygame.error as message:
            while True:
                self.next_file += 1
                if self.next_file == self.directory_limit:
                    self.next_file = 0
                self.music_file = self.file_path + "/" + self.filenames[self.next_file]
                if (".wav") or (".mp3") in self.music_file:
                    break
        mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
        mixer.music.play()
        ########################################################################################################      



root = tk.Tk()
MP(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think there was a huge chunk of code I deleted before I pasted it here

Comment: Why a huge space between the import statements and the code. No need of ```Tk()``` at the last. Also, ```root.mainloop()``` missing parenthesis was not calling the ```mainloop``` function ;-). Yes, you can add background images to the code. Using the PIL ```pip install pillow``` library, you can import ```ImageTk```. Or you can use the built in ```self.im1=PhotoImage(file='.....\file\path\to\image')```  and then use ```Button(win,image=self.im1)```

Comment: where do I put these

Comment: The last part is where ```Tk()``` is not needed and ```root.mainloop()``` is needed

Comment: I see thanks, the only issue now is that Next isn't showing up